# Proper Upsert (Atomic Update Counter Field or Insert Document) with RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

After looking at some SO questions and issues on RethinkDB github, I failed to come to a clear conclusion if atomic Upsert is possible?

Essentially I would like to perform the same operation as ZINCRBY using Redis.

> If member does not exist in the sorted set, it is added with increment
>   as its score (as if its previous score was 0.0). If key does not
>   exist, a new sorted set with the specified member as its sole member
>   is created.

The current implementation appears to differ from almost all databases that I have used. With the data being replaced or inserted not updated. This is a simple use case, like update the last visit, update the number of clicks, update a product quantity. So I must be missing something very obvious, because I cannot see a simple way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. After `get` on the key, perform an atomic `replace`. Something like this might work:

```
function set_or_increment_score(player, points){
  return r.table('scores').get(player).replace(
    row =>
      { id: player,
        score: r.branch(
                 row.eq(null),
                 points,
                 row('score').add(points))
      });
}
```

It has the following behaviour:

```
> set_or_increment_score("alice", 1).run(conn)
{ inserted: 1 }
> set_or_increment_score("alice", 2).run(conn)
{ replaced: 1 }
```

It works because `get` returns `null` when the document doesn't exist, and a `replace` on a non-existing document tuns into an insert. See the [documentation for replace](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/replace/)

Comment: Hi @AtnNm. Thanks for your reply, but I don't fully follow your example.

I have nothing to replace therefore the get will return a null or an error. I want to insert a row with the {name:"A", score:1, type:player}. If A is already in the table then I want to take the score and update it.

I want to insert the document or in case the document exists to increment the score. If I follow your example that function requires that the player already exists, and creates the score record or increments if it already exists.

Comment: The use case is similar to Redis zincrby or PouchDB https://github.com/pouchdb/upsert

Comment: The case where the player doesn't exist is handled by an `r.branch` on `row.eq(null)`. I've edited the answer with an example and a link to the documentation.

Comment: So its actually a replace, there is no update. Ok, good to know. I found a different way to do it using function to resolve the conflict, still seems like a really messed up way to simply update one field, at least compared to other data stores. Rethinking if I actually should use this RethinkDB :/

Comment: It's different but works well in practice. And if you add a `row.merge` it will only update the fields you want to change and not replace the whole document.

Comment: @AtnNm I wrote an answer with the code I am using. Tell me what you think of this approach and if there are advantages using your approach instead. Thank you very much for your input, super helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

So I end up using the following code to go around the no Update issue.

```
r.db("test").table("t").insert(
  {id:"A", type:"player", species:"warrior", score:0, xp:0, armor:0},
  {conflict: function(id, oldDoc, newDoc) {
       return newDoc.merge(oldDoc).merge(
         {armor: oldDoc("armor").add(1)});
   }
  }
)
```

Do you think this is more readable/elegant or do you see any issues with the code compared to your sample?